# ExecuteNonQuery. connection property has not been initialized

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

Hey guys im having this error on my codes but seems to work on the other new projects it always highlight the ExecuteNonQuery.
I tried to search for solution with google and this site but guys I really don't know why it had below error.

Also Im using in mssql express.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace AssetInsert
{
    public partial class AssetInsert : Form
    {
        public AssetInsert()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    private void ICButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DBConn.DBOpen();
        lbConnTest.Text = "OK";
        DBConn.DBClose();
    }
    private void ISaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sql = (@"INSERT INTO dbo.HWTable(Brand, CPU, RAM, HSerial, Model, ACode, PYear, UName, Position, Depart) VALUES('" + BrandCBox.Text + "', '" + CPUTBox.Text + "', '" + RAMTBox.Text + "', '" + HSerialTBox.Text + "', '" + ModelTBox.Text + "', '" + ACodeTBox.Text + "', '" + PYearPicker.Text + "', '" + UNameTBox.Text + "', '" + PositionCBox.Text + "', '" + DepartCBox.Text + "');");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql);
        DBConn.DBOpen();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Brand", BrandCBox.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CPU", CPUTBox.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RAM", RAMTBox.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HSerial", HSerialTBox.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Model", ModelTBox.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ACode", ACodeTBox.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PYear", PYearPicker.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UName", UNameTBox.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Position", PositionCBox.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Depart", DepartCBox.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //<--error here
        DBConn.DBClose();      
    }

    public class DBConn
    {
        public static void DBOpen()
        {
            string source = @"Data Source = 10.201.0.17; Initial Catalog = ITinven; USER ID = sa; PASSWORD = jc9989;";
            SqlConnection conn;
            conn = new SqlConnection(source);
            conn.Open();
        }

        public static void DBClose()
        {
            string source = @"Data Source = 10.201.0.17; Initial Catalog = ITinven; USER ID = sa; PASSWORD = jc9989;";
            SqlConnection conn;
            conn = new SqlConnection(source);
            conn.Close();
        }
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Error message is clear;

> **connection property has not been initialized**

Connect your `SqlComamnd` and `SqlConnection` like;

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
```

Weird part is, you add your insert values with string concatenation but also you try to add them as parameters also. Read: [Give me parameterized SQL, or give me death](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). And you don't need `DBOpen` and `DBClose` methods like this.

As a best practice, use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SqlComamnd` and `SqlConnection` instead of calling `.Close()` method manually in a different method, and stop using `AddWithValue` method. It *may* generate unexpected results. Use [`.Add()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or it's overloads instead.

Read: [Can we stop using `AddWithValue()` already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(source))
using(SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
   // Set your CommandText property with parameterized way.
   // Add your parameters with .Add() method
   // Open your connection
   // Execute your query.
}
```

When you get any error message or exception in your code, read them *carefully*. One more time, and one more time.. This makes *much* more easier to solve your problem.

Comment: @Karla Good to hear :)

Answer (score 0):

(1) Correct way to pass the parameters

(2) Always use try-catch block

(3) Correct way to initialise Sqlcommand with sqlcommand text and sql connection.

```
// see how parameters are used

SqlCommand sqlcommand0;

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(con_str))

{

    conn.Open();

    string sql = "INSERT INTO dbo.HWTable(Brand, CPU, RAM, HSerial, Model, ACode, PYear, UName, Position, Depart) VALUES(@Brand, @CPU, @RAM, @HSerial, @Model, @ACode, @PYear, @UName, @Position, @Depart)";       // (1)

    try                                                // (2)

    {

        using (sqlcommand0 = new SqlCommand(commandtext, conn)) // (3)

        {

            sqlcommand0.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Brand", Brand.Text));

            sqlcommand0.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CPU", CPU.Text));

            ....

            sqlcommand0.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }

    }

    catch

    {

        Console.WriteLine("Count not insert data into table.");

    }

}
```

Comment: Using parameterized queries is _always_ a better approach but I don't think this is the _real_ problem here.

Comment: But this should solve the problem, since the parameters Brand, CPU, ...etc. didn't exist in the sql statement, that's why I add them to the statement to make it work. Why -1 for it?

Comment: I didn't downvote but I think _only_ suggesting parameterized way doesn't make your answer _helpful_. Clearly, OP needs to connect his `SqlCommand` and `SqlConnection`. But you didn't _even_ mentioned it.

Comment: Using blockquotes instead of code formatting makes things really difficult to read. Consider fixing that.